# Вывод подкатегорий текущей или родительской категории по алфавиту с буквой в WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Нужно сделать вывод подкатегорий с розделением на блоки с буквами[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все очень просто: меняем get_posts на get_categories:

```
<ul>
    <?php           
    function get_first_letter($str) {
        return mb_substr($str, 0, 1, 'utf-8');
    }

    $args = array(
        'type'         => 'post',
        'orderby'      => 'name',
        'order'        => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'   => 0,
        'taxonomy'     => 'category',
    );
    $categories = get_categories($args);

    foreach ($categories as $k => $cat) {
        // first letter
        $fl = get_first_letter( $cat->name );
        $prev_fl = isset( $categories[ ($k-1) ] ) ? get_first_letter( $categories[ ($k-1) ]->name ) : '';
        if( $prev_fl !== $fl )
            echo '<li class="first-letter">' . $fl . '</li>';
    }

    for($i='a'; $i !='aa'; $i++) 
    echo('<li>' . $i . '</li>'); 
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</ul>
<ul class="abc-posts">
    <?php
    foreach ($categories as $k => $cat) {
        // first letter
        $fl = get_first_letter($cat->name);
        $prev_fl = isset( $categories[ ($k-1) ] ) ? get_first_letter( $categories[ ($k-1) ]->name ) : '';
        if( $prev_fl !== $fl )
            echo '<div class="wrap-letter"><span class="first-letter">' . $fl . '</span></div>';

        // info
        echo '<li class="item-abc"><a href="'.get_category_link($cat->term_id).'">'.$cat->name.'</a></li>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое это оно!!!!!
А чтоб вывести подкатегории нужно вывести еще 'parent'
$args = array(
        'type'         => 'post',
        'orderby'      => 'name',
        'order'        => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'   => 0,
        'taxonomy'     => 'category',
        'parent'    => 23,
    );